# How can I apply a function to multiple columns of grouped rows and make a column of the output?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, group-by, aggregate

I have a large excel file containing stock data loaded from and sorted from an API. Below is a sample of dummy data that is applicable towards solving this problem:

[image: dummydata.xlsx]

> I would like to create a function that Scores Stocks grouped by their **Industry**. For this sample I would like to score a stock a 5 if its ['Growth'] value is less than its groups **mean Growth**  (quantile, percentile) in Growth and a 10 if above the groups mean growth. The scores of all values in a column should be returned in a list

> Current Unfinished Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('dummydata.xlsx')
```

> Desired input:

```
data['Growth'].apply(score) # Scores stock
```

> Desired Output:

[5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5]

> If I can create a function for this sample then I will be able to make similar ones for different columns with slightly different conditions and aggregates (like percentile or quantile) that affect the score. I'd say the main problem here is accessing these grouped values and comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to convert from a Series to a list in the `apply` call. I may be wrong on that but if the desired output was changed slightly to

```
data['Growth'].apply(score).tolist()
```

then you can use a lambda function to do this.

```
score = lambda x: 5 if x < growth.mean() else 10
data['Growth'].apply(score).tolist() # outputs [5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5]
```

Comment: would this also be efficient to use on other columns with more conditions?

Comment: I believe it should be fine. The biggest issue with multiple conditions might be readability more than anything.